# Extracing IP addresses as whole words with POSIX BRE/ERE regex

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to match IP addresses found in the output of `traceroute` by means of a regex. I'm not trying to validate them because it's safe enough to assume `traceroute` is valid (i.e. is not outputting something like `999.999.999.999`. I'm trying the following regex:

```
([0-9]{1,3}.?){4}
```

I'm testing it in [regex101](http://www.regex101.com) and it does validate an IP address. However, when I try

```
echo '192.168.1.1 foobar' | grep '([0-9]{1,3}.?){4}'
```

I get nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: And if you use `grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4}'`? You used a POSIX ERE pattern, but did not pass `-E` option. Thus, POSIX BRE  was used by `grep`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked. Care to elaborate an answer so I can accept it? I also would like to see how would I solve my problem using BREs

Comment: I did not notice the comment, but I actually was working on this update, to show how BRE syntax can be used here.

Comment: just my opinion but since you know you are looking for an IP, something simple like \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b  would do the trick.  Making the \.? optional means that 1234 would be a valid IP match.  Or even w/o the \b would probably be fine.

Comment: Note the [How do you extract IP addresses from files using a regex in a linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427979/how-do-you-extract-ip-addresses-from-files-using-a-regex-in-a-linux-shell) post has no valid POSIX BRE/ERE solution for IP address as whole word extraction using `grep`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You used a POSIX ERE pattern, but did not pass `-E` option to have `grep` use the POSIX ERE flavor. Thus, `grep` used POSIX BRE instead, where you need to escape `{n,m}` quantifier and `(...)` to make them be parsed as special regex operators.

Note you need to escape a `.` so that it could only match a literal dot.

To make your pattern work with `grep` the way you wanted you could use:

```
grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4}'      # POSIX ERE
grep '\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\?\)\{4\}'  # POSIX BRE version of the same regex
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/j1M0dd).

**However**, this regex will also match a string of several digits because the `.` is optional.

You may solve it by unrolling the pattern as

```
grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}'      # POSIX ERE
grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}' # POSIX BRE
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/C5S458).

Basically, it matches:

- `[0-9]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 occurrences of any ASCII digit
- `(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}` - 3 occurrences of:

  - `\.` - a literal `.`
  - `[0-9]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 occurrences of any ASCII digit

To make sure you only match valid IPs, you might want to use a [more precise IP matching regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html):

```
grep -E '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\b' # POSIX ERE
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/Tp0VUn).

You may further tweak it with word boundaries (can be `\<` / `\>` or `\b`), etc.

**To extract the IPs** use `-o` option with `grep`: `grep -oE 'ERE_pattern' file` / `grep -o 'BRE_pattern' file`.

Comment: That regex [wont work](https://regex101.com/r/qFE95M/1). Use [this](https://regex101.com/r/qFE95M/2) instead.

Comment: @Olian04: I understand what you mean, I just translated OP regex into POSIX BRE/ERE. Edited.

Comment: @Olian04 Or a little shorter: `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}`. Still, this doesn't catch broken IP addresses (e.g. 256.256.256.256).

Comment: @VictorZamanian *You might want to use a [more precise IP matching regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html).* The answer just points out how to fix the current OP approach. There are more ways to match IPs and all that depends on what the use case is.

Answer (score 1):

To make a more effective validation, it is better to use a function instead of a simple regex match:

```
#!/bin/bash
is_valid_ip() {
  local arr element
  IFS=. read -r -a arr <<< "$1"                  # convert ip string to array
  [[ ${#arr[@]} != 4 ]] && return 1              # doesn't have four parts
  for element in "${arr[@]}"; do
    [[ $element =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]       || return 1 # non numeric characters found
    [[ $element =~ ^0[1-9]+$ ]]      || return 1 # 0 not allowed in leading position if followed by other digits, to prevent it from being interpreted as on octal number
    ((element < 0 || element > 255)) && return 1 # number out of range
  done
  return 0
}
```

You can invoke this as:

```
while read -r ip; do
  is_valid_ip "$ip" && printf '%s\n' "$ip" 
done < <(your command that extracts ip address like strings)
```

---

Related:

- [Check for IP validity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13777387/6862601)

Comment: Even though OP explicitly stated that a regex validation was enough, this is a great little function!