# Picking valid IPs from an array of strings

Tags: arrays, bash, ip-address

in my usecase i'm filtering certain IPv4s from the list and putting them into array for further tasks:

```
readarray -t firstarray < <(grep -ni '^ser*' IPbook.file | cut -f 2 -d "-")
```

As a result the output is:

```
10.8.61.10
10.0.10.15
172.0.20.30
678.0.0.10
```

As you see the last row is not an IP, therefore i faced an urge to add some regex check on the FIRSTARRAY. 
I do not want to save a collateral files to work with them, so i'm looking for some "on-the-fly" option to regex the firstarray. I tried the following:

```
for X in "${FIRSTARRAY[@]}"; do
  readarray -t SECONDARRAY < <(grep -E '\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b' "$X")
done
```

But in the output I see that system thinks that $X is a file/dir, and didn't process the value, even though it clearly sees it:

```
line ABC: 172.0.20.30: No such file or directory
line ABC: 678.0.0.10: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong and what would be the best approach to proceed?

Comment: Why not apply the `grep -E '\b...` expression to the command used for building the array in the first place?

Comment: I can, but i will still have to filter the IPs into another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `"$X"` as an argument to `grep` and hence it is being treated as a file.  Use herestring `<<<` instead:

```
for X in "${firstarray[@]}"; do
  readarray -t secondarray < <(grep -E '\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b' <<< "$X")
done
```

You are better off writing a function to validate the IP instead of relying on just a [regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44654809/6862601):

```
#!/bin/bash
validate_ip() {
  local arr element
  IFS=. read -r -a arr <<< "$1"                  # convert ip string to array
  [[ ${#arr[@]} != 4 ]] && return 1              # doesn't have four parts
  for element in "${arr[@]}"; do
    [[ $element =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]       || return 1 # non numeric characters found
    [[ $element =~ ^0[1-9]+$ ]]      || return 1 # 0 not allowed in leading position if followed by other digits, to prevent it from being interpreted as on octal number
    ((element < 0 || element > 255)) && return 1 # number out of range
  done
  return 0
}
```

And then loop through your array:

```
for x in "${firstarray[@]}"; do
  validate_ip "$x" && secondarray+=("$x") # add to second array if element is a valid IP
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you passing an argument to the `grep` command and it expects reading standard input instead.

You can use your regex to filter the IP addresses right in the first command:

```
readarray -t firstarray < <(grep -ni '^ser*' IPbook.file | cut -f 2 -d "-" | grep -E '\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b' )
```

Then you have only IP addresses in `firstarray`.