# var must contains a ip-adress, otherwise, stop, with error the var must be an ip-adress and nothing else

Tags: bash, variables, scripting, grep, ip

I want to check in Bash a Variable, if it contains a IP-Adress, otherwise the Script should exit with an errormessage.
For example :
The var "10.01.24.10" should pass, the var "hello" not, but the var "hello, my ip is 10.03.24.44" should pass not too.
My Idea would to use grep but I dont know how to build the grep command at this point.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any ideas to solve the problem, so I can't add code.

Comment: Then at least tell us what did you search for, and what did you find?

Comment: See: [Check for IP validity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13777387/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can incorporate the grep command in an if statement as below

```
ip="192.168.240.2" 


if grep -Eq '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}([0-9]{1,3})' <<< "$ip"
then 
  echo "PASS"
else 
  echo "FAIL"
fi
```

You can also write the conditional statements as:

```
grep -Eq '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}([0-9]{1,3})' <<< "$ip" && echo "PASS" || echo "FAIL"
```

This uses && to signify success and || to signify failure

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
ip="192.168.240"


if grep -Eq '^([0-9]{1,3}.){3}([0-9]{1,3})' <<< $ip
then
  echo "PASS"
else
  echo "FAIL"
fi
~
` If i run this, the script pass too, can i avoid this?

Comment: The author of this answer forgot to escape the dot `\.`; I have updated to fix this.